# Jenkins build using fastlane string parameter with whitespace

Tags: ios, xcode, jenkins, fastlane

Simple question, how to pass string parameter to build script that has whitespace in Jenkins?

Example: `DEVICE_NAME` value: iPhone 5
using it like this key: `${DEVICE_NAME}`
output `key: iPhone`

How to solve it ?

Edit: "iPhone 5" or 'iPhonr 5' or \'iPhone 5\' or iPhone\ 5 does not work.

Edit2: Sure
This is how I use it in Build Step/Execute Shell:

```
fastlane test_generic proj_name:${PROJ_NAME} proj_path:${PROJ_PATH} scheme_name:${SCHEME_NAME} device_name: ${DEVICE_NAME}
```

For Example when I use "iPhone 5" console output is:

```
device_name: '"iPhone' '5"'
```

Last edit: for other that will have this issue, just use this: `"$DEVICE_NAME"`

Comment: Just add a quotes, e.g. "iPhone 5"

Comment: I guess the issue is not at input but at the point of usage. No quoting or escaping needed to pass a whitespace into a Jenkins parameter. Where do you use this parameter, in a shell script? Could you provide a snippet of your code?